# URL with operators (=, -) not working within if-statement

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, cmd

I'm having an issue with an URL in an if-statement using batch.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET /P input="Insert Link "

if %input%==l (echo true) else (echo false)

cmd /k
```

I want to determine if the user input is a link or a single character (in this case `l`). I get that the operators within the URL might cause the problem. But shouldn't the if-statement just check if `%input%` is `l` and everything else would trigger the `else`? Using `SET %input%=l` leads to the true case being triggered.

Any ideas on how to make this work in a simple way? Am I missing something regarding syntax?

Comment: If you "want to determine if the user input is"... you need to use the correct `set` option: ```Set  /P "input=PromptString"```. The correct `If` command would be ```If "%input%" == "l" (Echo true) Else Echo false``` or ```If /I "%input%" == "l" (Echo true) Else Echo false``` (for `L` or `l`).

Comment: Of course. I was using `SET input=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zswl5YrvVw` for testing purposes. I'm going to edit the OP so my question and the given code are matching.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `%input%` and `l` within the if-statement in quotes solved the problem.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET /P input="Insert Link "

if "%input%"=="l" (echo true) else echo false

cmd /k
```

Answer (score -1):

The way the Command Line works, `%ThisIsAVariable%` will be replaced with whatever `ThisIsAVariable` contains and then be interpreted as such. Hence, running your example prompts the following error:

```bash
=6zswl5YrvVw==l was unexpected at this time.
```

The simplest way to solve this is to wrap your `%input%` with `""`

e.g.

```bash
@ECHO OFF

SET input=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zswl5YrvVw

if "%input%"==l (echo true) else (echo false)

cmd /k
```

That would prompt `false`

Comment: You'll want to put quotes around the `l` since quotes themselves are included in the comparison. You'll also want to wrap `input=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zswl5YrvVw` in quotes (so `set "input=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zswl5YrvVw"`).

Comment: The quotes did the trick. `if "%input%"=="l" (echo true) else (echo false)` it is. Thank you for your help and the explanation!

Comment: Please do not mark an answer as a solution to a problem when the answer does not solve that problem @fassimcgee. The above is so very wrong, and by accepting it you're potentially sending future readers down the wrong path. In the above code, only line 1 is acceptable.